# MomentJS next 15th

Tags: angularjs, node.js, momentjs

Im developing a simple application that show the daily budget until the next payment. For that I'm using momentJS.

The problem is that the logic in my application is wrong. Im, first finding what day is it, then I find the first day of the this month (`date(1)`), then I sum 1 month and 14 days. But whenever its the next month (as right now -02/12), it will, of course tell me that the next 15th is in February.

Long story short, how do I find the next 15th using moment?

Here is my application:

```
  $scope.nextDate = moment().date(1).add(1, "months").add(14,"days"); //calculate when is the next 15th
  $scope.difference = Math.floor(moment.duration($scope.nextDate.diff($scope.today)).asDays());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple condition in the `add` method when calculating the `nextDate`.

```
$scope.nextDate = moment().date(1).add((moment().date() > 14 ? 1 : 0), "months").add(14,"days");
```

This will either add 0 or 1 months to your calculation based on the condition if current date is larger than 14 (modify to 15 if you want to count "next" 15th as today when it's actually 15th)